# Binding a context menu in a WPF MVVM project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am struggling to understand where I'm going wrong with my MVVM WPF project. I am trying to create a custom contextmenu command. I have a workspace, which is a view, within a HCC in my MainWindow. The workspace (ProductRecordView) contains a listview populated by an observable collection by the viewmodel (ProductRecordViewModel). The data context is set by [Option 8](http://paulstovell.com/blog/mvvm-instantiation-approaches), in the MainWindowResources XAML. So I have created the contextmenu in the PRV as follows:

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteRecord}"/>
  </ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

and in the PRVM I have the following things:

```
#region Presentation Properties

public ICommand DeleteRecord
{
    get
    {
        if (_deleteMe == null)
        {
            _deleteMe = new RelayCommand(
                param => this.Delete(),
                param => this.CanDelete
                );
        }

        return _deleteMe;
    }
}

#endregion Presentation Properties

#region Public Methods

public void Delete()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test Execute");//this is just for testing the binding of Delete
}

#endregion Public Methods

#region Private Helpers

bool CanDelete = false; //this is just for testing the binding of CanDelete

#endregion Private Helpers
```

When I run the application and right click on an item in the list view, I am presented with the context menu as described in the first snippet, however it is not binding as intended as neither of the bound outcomes occur. How do I properly bind in this case, what am I doing wrong?

The DataContext of ProductRecordView is set in MainWindowResources as follows:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductRecordViewModel}">
  <vw:ProductRecordView />
</DataTemplate>
```

I know that this DataContext is working as intended as if I try to create a button in the view and assign a data binding to it, the binding works perfectly and executes the command in the ProductRecordViewModel

Comment: Check the Output window, you probably have a binding error. Can you provide that? Also, using RelativeSource Self doesn't look right, are sure you're binding to the correct element?

Comment: @MikeEason Yes I should have probably said in my question; here is the error: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DeleteRecord' property not found on 'object' ''ListCollectionView' (HashCode=12713695)'. BindingExpression:Path=DeleteRecord; DataItem='ListCollectionView' (HashCode=12713695); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand') but I have no idea what that means or how to fix it :(

Comment: define x:name on your view and in MenuItem write  <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding ElementName=yourViewName Path=DataContext.DeleteRecord}"/>

Comment: In English: "The path to DeleteRecord was not found in ListCollectionView". Your binding is incorrect. Give a name to the element where you are setting the data context and change the binding to ElementName=xxx instead of RelativeSource

Comment: @MikeEason I took both of your answers and tried to fix it based on them, but I have the same outcome.

Comment: Please show us how do you define the `DataContext` and the `ItemsSource` for your `ListView`.

Comment: @dymanoid See the edits above :)

Comment: @LewisHeslop, it's still unclear what's the `vw:ProductRecordView`. Is this an `UserControl` that contains a `ListView`?

Comment: @dymanoid yes it is a user control that contains a listview and it is assigned to a tabview (workspace) on the MainWindow.

Comment: @user2941906 If I remember correctly, a ContextMenu is not part of the visual tree, so it cannot see named elements.

Comment: @sondergard you are correct and this is exactly why users answer had no effect. The issue is now figuring how to get around that  problem

Comment: @LewisHeslop The code _should_ work - I have done it the same way several times. This leads me to believe the problem is elsewhere in the XAML. Check my answer and see if that is the problem, otherwise please provide a bit more of the XAML code.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the error message more precisely.

> BindingExpression path error: 'DeleteRecord' property not found on
>   'object' ''ListCollectionView' (HashCode=12713695)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DeleteRecord; DataItem='ListCollectionView'
>   (HashCode=12713695); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

This states, that the data binding system tries to find a `DeleteRecord` property in the `MenuItem`'s `DataContext` which is of type `ListCollectionView`.

So, considering your expression

```
DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

it's clear that the `PlacementTarget.DataContext` is of type `ListCollectionView` too. Since `PlacementTarget` is the `ListView` itself, it's obvious that the `ListView`'s `DataContext` is this `ListCollectionView` object.

I suppose, you define your `ListView`'s `DataContext` somehow like this:

```
<ListView DataContext="{Binding Items}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

The better solution would be to leave the `ListView`'s `DataContext` alone so that it "inherits" it's value from your `UserControl` (thus will be of type `ProductRecordViewModel`) while changing the binding for the `ItemsSource`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why is the ProductRecordView in a datatemplate? I get the suspicion that the list items are PRV which is each bound to a PRVM - is that correct? Something like this

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteRecord}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductRecordViewModel}">
            <vw:ProductRecordView /> <!-- each PRV is bound to a PRVM - which as the delete record command -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If that is the case, then the problem is that datacontext of the listviewitems is not the same as the listview itself. Instead you probably want the context menu on the listviewitems directly:

```
<ListView>        
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductRecordViewModel}">
                <vw:ProductRecordView>
                    <vw:ProductRecordView.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteRecord}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    <vw:ProductRecordView.ContextMenu>
                </vw:vw:ProductRecordView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```